# How does cloud_to_laserscan.cpp work

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some more qns regarding cloud_to_scan.cpp. the post was previously posted[http://answers.ros.org/question/1561/doubts-about-pointcloud-to-laser-scan] but it was not answered. I am in need of urgent help.

Qn 1)if (output->ranges[index] * output->ranges[index] > range_sq) output->ranges[index] = sqrt(range_sq);, what is this statement trying to do.. not that sure...

qn 2) is the x, y and z in metres?or what are the units for the x,y and z?

qn 3) why is  the angle = -atan2(x,z) and not angle = -atan2(z,x)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10722/how-does-cloud_to_laserscan.cpp-work/) by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-07-25

Post score: -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All your questions can be answer by reviewing [REP 103 Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-07-27**:
At least 3 is also answered. Look at the coordinate axis definitions in the REP and the definition of the tangent function as found in your favorite math book. 1 apparently just limits range readings to some maximum.

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-07-27**:
sorry, from REP103, qn 2 was answered but not qn 1 and 3... or maybe i can't find it... need more explaination. sorry.